# How to speed up REBOUND python simulations on a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: astrophysics, python, n-body-simulations

I'm running Python based computational astrophysics simulations on a Jupyter notebook, with the help of a library called REBOUND (also using REBOUNDx), to create a simulation containing the solar system. The code I write runs properly and gives me the expected results. The problem I'm having right now is that if I set the simulation for a few gigayears, it takes at least 8 hours to get the results. Is there any way to optimise my code so that it runs faster?

The code is written in three files as follows:

1. The setup.py file contains the initial conditions and all the objects of the simulation.
2. The restart.py file is where the simulation runs and takes an extraordinary amount of time for just 3 objects so this is what I'd like to optimise.
3. The follow.py file is where the data from the simulation archive binary file is plotted for analysis.

I've tried Numba's JIT but it doesn't work because it doesn't work with other libraries or data outside of the function you've applied JIT to. I've also considered paying for more hardware computational power on IDEs such as Google's Colab, but I wanted to check if there's a software trick I can exploit. Please let me know.

Comment: what books do you use?  I would like to know.

Comment: My how the world has changed since I first studied Astronomy; complaining that a few gigayears takes a whole 8 hours to simulate... :-)

Comment: Gyr is actually a lot for 8 hours of working in local. Just a comment from someone who has used (not much though) REBOUNDx... Have you tried getting in touch with the Contributors? (Hanno Rein, Dan Tamayo, David Spiegel, Akihiko Fujii). "[REBOUND](https://pypi.org/project/rebound/0.1.9/) is open source. You are invited to contribute to this project if you are using it. Please contact any of the authors above if you have any questions."

Answer (score 4):

You're probably better off asking in a programming SE to be honest.

You seem to have already done the work of making sure that your python / numpy / numba installation is set up properly so as much of the work is done in C as possible, so it's unlikely there's more performance to be gained there.

Otherwise, the first thing to do is to run a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) to see exactly where computation time is being spent. It might give more helpful answers if you first [refactor](https://realpython.com/python-refactoring/) your code into more, smaller functions that call each other rather than a few big ones (it also makes debugging much easier). If the bulk of the time spent is in your code, you have a chance to optimise it. If it's in libraries that you're calling, you're less likely to be able to do anything about it.

As a preliminary I've had a quick look through your code and while there are some unpythonic things there, nothing stands out as being hugely slow. The only thing is the triple-nested loop starting at line 150 in restart.py. You want to avoid nested loops as much as possible as it increases the time complexity of your code. In fact, you want to avoid loops if you can, doing things with numpy arrays where possible. Also, writing to file can also be slow, it's better to keep it in RAM and do big lumps of it rarely rather than constantly doing small amounts of it.

But, at the end of the day, the sad truth is python just isn't that fast. I've done my fair share of scientific research computing in it and while it has the advantage of being very easy to develop in, it just isn't fast or efficient in computing resources. If you want to push the envelope of what can be computed, consider an other language (C is a favourite, Rust or Julia are gaining ground, Fortran if you're very old and/or brave). If you just want a data point for a paper, then grinding your teeth and taking a while to calculate might be easier than spending weeks learning and writing in a new language. Note that your problem seems like it might be easily parallelisable (by having different simulations with different initial conditions running independently of each other), so paying for many not-very-particularly-fast cores on a cloud service might work as is. At the end of the day it depends on your priorities and on the relative value you place on computer time vs your time vs money.

Comment: As far as I know, I believe [REBOUND](https://pypi.org/project/rebound/0.1.9/), and "[REBOUNDx](https://reboundx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are written in C, but we also provide a convenient Python wrapper (that’s just as fast)."